# Make a command to open c files next to the corresponding header

Tags: vimrc, command-line

I would like to have commands like :ce and :ctabe that open a tab with a vertical split with the .c file on one site and the corresponding .h file on the other. How can i accomplish this behaviour?

Comment: If you search this site for “custom command” there are lots of examples. Then it’s a matter of figuring out the commands to open the appropriate files. As it stands, your question is a little unclear and could use some additional detail to define the problem and what a good solution looks like

Answer (score 1):

Custom commands cannot start with lowercase letters, but you can define for example `:Ce` and `:Ctabe`.

Here's a custom function that does the same as `:edit {file}`:

```
command! -nargs=1 -complete=file Ce edit <args>
```

In order to open another related file, you would use `:vsplit`; the current file can be referenced via the [`:help cmdline-special`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#cmdline-special) notation `%`. `%:r` gives you the current file without its file extension. So the following will open the corresponding header file:

```
command! -nargs=1 -complete=file Ce edit <args> | vsplit %:r.h
```

PS: There are several plugins that do something like that, too. A very old one is [a.vim](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=31). A modern one is [projectionist.vim](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4989).